leverage of new predicted value
I would like to find the leverage of the new predicted values in my regression. Below is an example code
how would I be able to find the leverage for the 2 new predicted values ?
data("mtcars")



mod = lm(mpg ~ wt +cyl,data=mtcars)

X = model.matrix(mod)

# Calculate hat matrix
H = X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)

#Leverage of Fitted Values 
leverage = diag(H)

new_dt = data.table(wt = c(2.5,3.456),cyl=c(4,8))
pred = predict(mod, newdata = new_dt)



I tried creating a new hat matrix, but this time including the two new data observations of wt and cyl however that was not correct.

Note: you can use hat(X) or hatvalues(mod) to get the leverage.

I don't understand what you mean by "leverage of new predicted value". Predictions have no impact on the model fit. I don't see how the concept of leverage would apply in this case. With predicted values (from extreme values of the IV) I would be concerned about, e.g., extrapolation.
